# Concatenate mulitple arrays into a string in Google BigQuery

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, concatenation

My bigquery table data looks like shown below

[image]

But I am trying to concatenate the array values to achieve an output like below.

SATURDAY;12;23|WEDNESDAY;0;15 as a single column value

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include the schema of your table and a sample (as `INSERT` statements) to help people reproduce your issue and help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you going in the right direction.  Ignore the top 2 CTEs as they are just replicating your sample data.

```
with 
-- recreating sample data
temp as (
    select 5046528 as LineID, 'Saturday' as positions, 12 as starttime, 23 as endtime   union all 
    select 5046528, 'Wednesday', 0, 15
),
-- formatting to recreate sample data structure
data as (
    select LineID, array_agg(struct(positions)) as day_part, array_agg(struct(starttime, endtime)) as hour_part
    from temp
    group by 1
)
-- Logic that is relevant to the question
select 
    LineID,
    string_agg(safe.concat(upper(d.positions),';',h.starttime,';',h.endtime),'|') as new_column
from data, unnest(day_part) d with offset as d_offset, unnest(hour_part) h with offset as h_offset
where d_offset = h_offset -- needed since you are unnesting 2 arrays, this makes sure your records "line up"
group by 1
```

Comment: The code suggested by you worked and helped me resolve the issue. Thank you so much for your time and effort. Sorry for the late response.